# Background для item RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

Для элементов RecyclerView использую CardView. Хотелось бы сделать каждый пункт списка таким.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинку фоновую подготовить не проблема. Размеры CardView я не указываю у меня указаны match_parent и wrap_content. Не знаю каких размеров сделать фоновый рисунок, чтобы он нормально смотрелся на телефонах и на планшетах.

Есть предложения? Или мне обязательно нужно указать ширину и высоту itemа для телефонов и планшетов и уже под них делать фон? Как делают опытные разработчики? vector drawable пока не интересует

Comment: Эмм..., а текст *коробка с карандашами...* и проч. это тоже фон? Или фон только овал с синеньким?

Comment: Фон это только овал. Тексты и иконка не нужна

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы фоновый рисунок нормально смотрелся на телефонах и на планшетах, лучше всего создать фоновое изображение квадратным. Размер будет зависеть от сложности изображения. Например если вы хотите создать кнопку с простым градиентом по краям, достаточно размера 100х100px, но внутри изображения нужно сделать отступ c каждой стороны в 2px, итого размер кнопки будет 98х98px.

Воспользуемся для работы сайтом
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example

Данный сайт обусловлен простотой и удобством использования, хотя в студии есть аналогичный инструмент, но, на мой взгляд, он менее удобен.
Так что рассмотрим работу с изображением на этом сайте.
Как только вы создали фоновое изображение, возьмите его и загрузите на сайт.
Для этого достаточно перенести ваше изображение в центр экрана или нажать кнопку "Select image" и указать путь к вашему изображению.

[image: Перетащите изображение на сайт]

Далее вам необходимо настроить границы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установите границы примерно таким образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В правом блоке можно увидеть результат масштабирования.
Обратите внимание, что текст вылезает за пределы вашего фонового изображения,
для того чтобы этого избежать, следующим шагом нужно настроить границы контента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите в правом блоке текст теперь находится внутри заданных границ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осталось сохранить изображение, жмите на кнопку сохранить и сайт автоматически сохранит в необходимых размерах и запакует в zip архив.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри архива будет папка res, а внутри будут папки с изображением под необходимые размеры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Такие штуки гораздо проще, быстрее и удобней делать в **векторе**. Что-бы нарисовать подобный фон, нужно буквально 2 минуты. На любых экранах будет выглядеть отлично и большинство проблем связанных с этим просто исчезают.

По [ссылке](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12oMIlmyRCvkPVEe0sJ5aU9VDworwjHRF/view?usp=sharing) можно скачать готовый `.xml` фон в векторе, срисованный с вашей картинки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**КАК ЭТО СДЕЛАТЬ?**

Шаг 1. В любом векторном редакторе, например *Adobe Illustrator* или *CorelDraw*, рисуете прямоугольник и настраиваете углы/заливку/градиент/прочее. С прямоугольниками это довольно просто, но для более сложных вещей, придется потратить пару часов на освоение базовых возможностей программы.

Шаг 2. Экспортируете результат в формате `svg`. Чтобы **Android Studio** правильно скушал ваш файл, его параметры должны быть следующими:

```
Стили - Атрибуты представления
Шрифт - SVG
Изображения - Встроить
ID объектов - Имена слоев
Точность - 2
Уменьшение файла - включено
Адаптивность - включено
```

Шаг 3. В *Android Studio* добавляете ваш файл через *Vector Asset*. Выбираете пункт *Local file* и указываете к нему путь. Нажимаете кнопку **Finish** - все готово, файл можно использовать.

**СОВЕТЫ**

Никогда не используйте обводку в `svg`. Если нужна обводка, то перед экспортом, переведите ее в кривые.

Не используйте растровые эффекты вроде теней или свечения. Их легко нарисовать вектором. Есть много туториалов на эту тему.

Если в вашем векторе используется простой линейный или круговой градиент, то лучше сохраните файл с обычной заливкой. А градиент настройте уже в *Android Studio*. Это позволит, при необходимости, быстро менять его цвета прямо в *IDE*. Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45135828/8013212) хорошо и понятно описывается работа с круговым градиентом. С линейным вообще все просто - `startColor`, `centerColor`, `endColor`.

Так можно делать не только с фоном для кнопок и айтемов. Любые иконки и кастомные элементы интерфейса сохраненные в векторе - очень сильно облегчают жизнь.

Comment: По ссылке layout разметка, товарищ :)

Comment: @Flippy, перепутал файл. Теперь все ок )

Comment: Ответу сильно не хватает инструкций о том, как самостоятельно сделать это в векторе. Мне вот, как не дизайнеру ваш ответ не поможет решить проблему)

Comment: разве VectorDrawable поддерживает градиенты? вы на устройстве тестировали или как в проекте использовать предлагаете

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вы правы, дополню ответ инструкцией.

Comment: @pavlofff, при сохранении вектора в `svg`, градиенты рисуются как последовательные слои разного цвета. В прикрепленном файле это как раз хорошо видно. Чтобы использовать в проекте, просто указываете на него `android:background="@drawable/svg_background"`.

Comment: Добавил инструкцию в ответ.